# Get index of ngFor item and update value

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to update the text values of input fields in my Angular template. The template data values are generated in an NgFor loop which gets values from a web service. Here is my template.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu">
  <li>
    <table>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item?.id}}</button></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bcluster"></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bsector"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id={{item?.id}} (click)="update($event)">Update</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bgroup"></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bunit"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id={{item?.id}} (click)="delete($event)">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>

  </li>
</ul>
```

I now need to get the values of the fields i.e 'bcluster, bsector, bgroup, bunit' from the template into my TS file in order to call the update API call(via a click event on the update button), however when I try to get the values I get undefined because I am not get the exact line index. Im not sure how to do this.

Here is my TS file(just trying to get the values consoled out)

```
  update(event) {
    console.log(this.bcluster);
  }
```

Comment: You pass the $event instead of that just pass “item” and in your update(item) { console.log(item); }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass item and index from the template something like

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu; let i = index;">
  <li>
    <table>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item?.id}}</button></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bcluster"></td>
            <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.bsector"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id={{item?.id}} (click)="update(item,i)">Update</button></td>
          </tr>
      </table>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Than in ts

```
update(item,idx) {
    //here idx will give you the index
    console.log(item.bcluster);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update ul to define index

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu; let i = index">
```

and use i as your function parameter

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
*ngFor="let item of vals?.bu; let i = index;"
```

You can now pass `i` to your function.